# If I have successfully opened a new tab in a browser, how can I write information to the screen from the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

my view that opens a new tab and calls a method in my controller called PrintConfirm():

```
 <a href="<%= Url.Action("PrintConfirm","Dashboard", new { id = Model.Data.Id })%>" rel="external" target="_blank"><button data-role="button" ui-icon="print">Print Confirmation</button></a>
```

my controller that creates a message to be shown in the new tab that I have opened

```
public void PrintConfirm(id)
{
    var message = "my message that I want to be able to print";
    //what should I put here in order to have this message show up on the screen?
}
```

I do not know how to make this show up on screen without HTML/view

Comment: How do you want display something in asp.net-MVC without HTML/View?!

Comment: I want it to be similar to a pdf without having it to be downloaded

Comment: If I cannot do it this way, how would I have my message appear within the view?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  Everything you write to the browser is technically "downloaded".  Regardless, the browser has to know how to display the content whether it's PDF, html or whatever.  There is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET MVC controller actions return ActionResults. They are not `void`.

```
public ActionResult PrintConfirm(int id)
{
    var message = "my message that I want to be able to print";
    return Content(message);
}
```

or return a view:

```
public ActionResult PrintConfirm(int id)
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "my message that I want to be able to print";
    return View();
}
```

and inside the corresponding template (`PrintConfirm.aspx`):

```
<div>
    <%= ViewData["Message"] %>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE:

According to the comments it seems that the message you want to display contains new lines (`\r\n`) and you want to display those new lines in the resulting view.

In this I would recommend you writing a custom HTML helper that will replace those new lines by `<br/>` tags:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString FormatMessage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object message)
    {
        var result = string.Join(
            "<br/>",
            Convert
                .ToString(message)
                .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select(x => htmlHelper.Encode(x))
            );
        return new HtmlString(result);
    }
}
```

and in the view you could simply use this helper like this:

```
<%= Html.FormatMessage(ViewData["Message"]) %>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!! (The first one is what I used) thank you so much!

Comment: @gdoron, yes, you are dreaming. And that's a nightmare :-)

Comment: The only problem that I am having now is that it is not recognizing line returns ?

Comment: @user1229309, what is not recognizing? You are getting an error message or something? In HTML you could use the `<br/>` tag to create line breaks or group in `<div>` elements the output. If in your message you just have `\r\n` new lines you will have to replace those with `<br/>` tags. A custom HTML helper could be appropriate to achieve this task in the view.

Comment: the message shows up on the screen but when I do "message one\n message 2", it prints "message onemessage two"

Comment: What can I do within the controller?

Comment: @user1229309, replace the new lines with `<br/>`. But it's better to do this in a custom helper in the view.